# Disable connection pool on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

How can I disable default connection pooling on Tomcat?
Is there any Resource parameter for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can configure another (custom) resourcefactory in your context.xml that doesn't use the dbcp. It's described in the [jndi-resources-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)